# SSIS script task fail version15.0 script when executing through SQL Agent

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-agent-job, script-task

I know this do the trick by deploying pkg through Visual Studio as I was also facing the same issue.

But recently my DBA, told me that he is not fine with installing visual studio on PROD in order to deploy packages. Is there any workaround for this as I can't install visual studio on PROD server still want to get  rid of this error.

I tried degrading pgk version to 2015/2016 in TargetServerVersion but it didn't work, still facing the same issue.

Do we have to have visual studio if our SSIS pkg contain script task ?

Comment: No, thats not a requirement, but you need to the same server versions.

Comment: did you consider using windows scheduler ?

Comment: Windows scheduler is out of option :(

Comment: Hi plaidDK, 
For keeping same version of SSDT and VS : 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  Version 14.0.17177.0
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017   Version 15.3.2
are my both versions at same level ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced that issue before and the fix was registering the dll in the server. You don't need to install VS.